# return inside controller actions MVC cakePHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp, controller

I have a simple question here. Is it really a bad idea to have a controller action return something (using return $something;). Is this good or bad MVC practice?

I know good MVC practice requires controllers to pass data to a view, but what if I have just a standalone function that is not going to use any views? Can I not just return the value of that function?

Thanks in advance experts

Comment: If you aren't using a 'View' how are you getting the data back to the user?

Comment: It's just a standalone function that performs a particular task which does not require any views (like a delete function for example). Delete controller actions does not have any views.

Comment: If it doesn't require a view, why are you returning anything? If it's a delete function you could set a flash message, and then redirect at the end of the action - that wouldn't require a view.

Comment: @user765368 , actually "good MVC practices" require the view to request data from model layer. Controller should only change the state, instead of gathering data. Look up how MVC is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it isn't so much a "bad idea" to return values from a controller action as it is "this isn't how CakePHP works".  If you want a response sent to the user you need to give this to a 'View'.  In your example you have a delete action that doesn't need to send a view back to the user.  I would attest that it does need to send a view.  Maybe the 'View' that you send back just needs to be a JSON response stating whether or not the deletion was successful and not an entire HTML document.

The 'View' is what sends the data to the user.  Let the 'View' take care of these responsibilities and don't try to make the Controller start doing too much.